# Correct c++ codes get warnings in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

The simple C++ codes generate random numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        cout << rand()%10 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty sure it is correct. But it received bug icon warnings in Eclipse even if it was compiled perfectly in Eclipse.

When hover on the bug on line with "srand" it shows: Multiple markers at this line
    - Function 'time' could not be 
     resolved
    - Function 'srand' could not be 
     resolved

When on the bug on line with "rand": Multiple markers at this line
    - Function 'rand' could not be 
     resolved
    - Invalid overload of 'endl'

The version of Eclipse is Mars (4.5.0) on Mac OS X 10.11. gcc version is 4.2.1

Comment: And your question is what exactly? :)

Comment: It's been a while since I used eclipse but I believe if you hover the mouse over the bug icon it should given you some description of the warning.  Please disregard if I am incorrect.

Comment: How can i get rid of the warnings on the window?

Comment: What are the warnings you get? What compiler are you using and what version is it? Please **edit your post** and include this and any other relevant information there.